# Bootstrap tags input in angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap tags input not working for me in angularjs. I tried everything, but nothing, it just adds area box and i cant even write something into.

```
<bootstrap-tagsinput ng-model="currentInventory.tags" itemvalue="value" itemtext="text"></bootstrap-tagsinput>
```

[LINK TO BOOSTRAP TAGS](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#angular)

Comment: Since you're using angularjs have you considered looking into [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/)? Here is their [demo page](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos).

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.js and register `bootstrap-tagsinput` in your Angular JS application to use the bootstrap-tagsinput directive.

1. Add script in your `index.html`
2. Add `bootstrap-tagsinput` in your module, like this:

   ```js
   angular.module('yourModule',[
     'ngRoute',
     'ngResources',
     'bootstrap-tagsinput'
   ]);
   ```

Comment: @Erick, did it work for you? for me as well, its not working! :( lemme what you did for this?

Comment: After reading source, I found the angular support was dropped. Though, the angular file is there, it is not updated to the latest API.

Answer (score -1):

In your bootstrap-tagsinput, you also need to specify typeahead-source, as shown in the [example here](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#angular).
Updated link in lieu of the non-functioning like above: [Angular Example](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap-2.3.2.html) Look for the "AngularJS support" section and click "Show code"

Comment: page not found.